Text Size and Boldness Issues on iOS App Store Version (Correct on Simulators)
I’m encountering an issue with my Flutter app where text sizes appear correctly on simulators but become larger and bolder when users download the app from the App Store. The issue seems to be specific to iOS devices.
Here are some details about my setup:
I’m using custom fonts configured in pubspec.yaml.
I am using the ScreenUtil package.
Text styles are defined consistently throughout the app.
I’ve checked font scaling and tested on simulators without issues.
Has anyone experienced similar problems, and can you suggest possible solutions or debugging steps to address this discrepancy between the simulator and real devices?
the first image is what it should look like.
[image 1]
the second image:
[image 2]
how to solve solve it.
For Android it works fine but the issue is in ios.
I have tried everything and search google but didn't get the answer.

could you submit a bit of code of how you use it?
anyway are you sure that you're using await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize(); in main function?
